# My aura:if conditional for label not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to update the label for a lightning component based on if a field is populated or not. I've tried a ton of things, and so far nothing is working (only the else statement is appearing):

```
<aura:attribute name="opportunity" type="Opportunity"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{or(v.opportunity.sample_id__c == null, v.opportunity.sample_id__c == '')}">
    <ui:button label="Create Sample" press="{!c.generateSampleWindow}"/>
<aura:set attribute="else">
    <ui:button label="View Sample" press="{!c.generateSampleWindow}"/>
</aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

I've also tried simply `isTrue="{!v.opportunity.sample_id__c}"`, but also doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing the `bang` (`!`)

Do it like this:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! or(v.opportunity.sample_id__c == null, v.opportunity.sample_id__c == '')}">
```

Also, to just check that the `isTrue` statement is set up properly, try defining and new attribute, say `testBoolean` to verify everything is working as it should (which, as you mentioned in the comments, it is not). Ie:

```
<aura:attribute name="testBoolean" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.testBoolean}">
    <div>It works!!</div>
</aura:if>
```

Also, as mentioned in other answers, you can simplify your expression a lot and just calculate the value of the label.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, but I appreciate the response (and it seems like it should work... not sure why it isn't).

Comment: What you need to do is check for case sensitivity, the name, the data in the name. Use a console print statement or an alert or the Javascript debugger if you can. Basically that syntax is correct, which says that something else is not.

Answer (score 7):

And instead of using the `aura:if` you can simply use the ternary inside the label of the button like this and yes you also have to fix the binding issue using `!`:

```
<aura:attribute name="opportunity" type="Opportunity"/>

<ui:button 
label="{!(empty(v.opportunity.sample_id__c)? 'Create Sample': 'View Sample')}"
press="{!c.generateSampleWindow}"/>
```

And to check for `null` and `''`, You can use the `empty` method.

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately this did not work either.

Comment: The syntax is correct, you just need to correct the attribute name. And also do share how you make it work.